# Bound copy of tikz manual

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is maybe a bit of a crazy question, and I hope it's not off topic, but: I find myself using tikz more and more, but the manual is a >1000 page pdf file. For me personally (I'm sure others have different experiences), the need to read it off a screen makes it very hard to navigate.

So my question is simply, is it possible to obtain a bound paper copy of the tikz/pgf manual at a reasonable price? Printing it all myself isn't feasible, but I'd be quite happy to pay for it in a book format.

I had a look on Amazon in case anyone was offering it as a print-on-demand book, but I didn't find anything that looked promising. I would need a service that can deliver to Japan, but if there are answers that are specific to other countries, they might be helpful to others.

Comment: If you bring the pdf to a copy shop they will print and bind it for you. Have you already tried? Does it cost too much?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I haven't tried. To be honest I didn't even think of ordering it as a one-off, as I assumed that would be expensive. But I don't really know.

Comment: There are various type of binding, maybe you could choose something less expensive than the one for thesis. I've never tried online copy shops (surely they exist).

Comment: Another wrinkle is that the tikz manual makes heavy use of colour, but not all of the colour is actually necessary for understanding it. It seems that print shops charge differently for colour vs black and white pages, so ideally, someone would have to go through and figure out which pages actually *need* to be printed in colour, so that the rest can be done in black and white.

Comment: Yes, the cost is _much_ more for colored pages

Answer (score 3):

I did make a hard copy of version 2, of "only" 560 pages in b/w, bound with wire which is the cheapest.
At current prices, it would cost around 33€.
The latest version of +1000 pages will cost around the double.

A single b/w copy costs 0.05€ while a colour one costs 0.37€, so printing in colour is not feasible.

In any case, I would recommend you against making a hard copy.
It is too big and it is very difficult to find the information you are looking for.
Then, it will become outdated pretty soon.
A pity for such an expensive book.

The digital copy is at least searchable, although that does not help much.
There are too many results.
I prefer to use the digital version 2 copy for the most common things because it is more likely that you will find it.

On the other hand, when you become more proficient, you do not need extensive information, but only a hint on how to use a command or some syntax.
Normally, you end up searching through Google on a specific *Tikz* topic and will be redirected to TeX.SE.
There are more than 27.000 Q/A related to *Tikz*.
More info than in the manual and easier to find.

So, what I do now is a quick search in the digital manual and then a search in Tex.SE.
I have not used the printed copy in many years.

Comment: Yeah, I get most of my tikz information from TeX.SE too. It just seems a bit of a shame, because great though this site is, the information is very piecemeal, and answers very often just consist of code without explanation. It's obvious that a huge amount of work has gone into the tikz manual, and I was trying to work out how I can get the most of that, given that I have a hard time reading it off a screen. You're probably right, though, that a bound copy wouldn't be much more practical either. I really wish there was just a concise 30-page overview manual.

Answer (score 2):

This is a self-answer, just to point out that nowadays there is an (unofficial) online version of the tikz manual, at https://tikz.dev. Either this didn't exist when I asked this question or I didn't know about it, but I find it much easier to search and navigate than the pdf, and that greatly reduces my desire for a hardcopy.

Comment: It didn't exist when you posted the question. According to [the project's readme](https://github.com/DominikPeters/pgf-tikz-html-manual) it was started in December of 2021. While it has it flaws, in many instances the online version is much better than the PDF version in my opinion.